# NPM- Dependent package not updating

Tags: jenkins, npm, protractor

I am using grunt-protractor-runner which pull down the latest minor version of protractor.  There was a bug in protractor version 2.5 https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2588 that was causing my tests to fail. I confirmed it was using that version by looking at the logs on jenkins which we use to build

```
21:56:58 grunt-protractor-runner@2.0.0 node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner
21:56:58 ├── split@0.3.3 (through@2.3.8)
21:56:58 ├── through2@0.5.1 (xtend@3.0.0, readable-stream@1.0.33)
21:56:58 └── protractor@2.5.0 (jasminewd@1.1.0, jasminewd2@0.0.6, html-   entities@1.1.3, q@1.0.0, minijasminenode@1.1.1, optimist@0.6.1, adm-  zip@0.4.4, glob@3.2.11, accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0, saucelabs@1.0.1, jasmine@2.3.2, source-map-support@0.2.10, request@2.57.0, selenium-webdriver@2.47.0)
```

Protractor released a new minor version about 5 hours ago 2.5.1 however when my build runs on jenkins it is still pulling down 2.5.0. I don't understand why. I looked at the package.json for grunt-protractor runner at https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner/blob/master/package.json and it defines the protractor as

```
"dependencies": {
"protractor": "^2.0.0",
"split": "~0.3.0",
"through2": "~0.5.1"
  },
```

So it should pull the latest minor version if i understand the '^' correctly. Is there something else that needs to be done for my dependent's dependency to pull down correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When I install grunt-protractor-runner with npm (version 3.3.3), protractor@2.5.1 is installed:

[image]

You have two options:

1. Try removing your node modules folder with `cd project-dir/ && rm -r node_modules/` and then rerunning `npm install` to do a fresh install of your dependencies.
2. I installed `grunt-protractor-runner@2.1.0` where you have version `2.0.0`. Try updating the package to see if the protractor version updates with it.

Comment: I updated my package json for grunt-protractor-runner from ~2.0 to ~2 and did an npm install. Then when into the node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner and did an npm install then a npm list and this is what I got back grunt-protractor-runner@2.1.0 /workspaces/<package>/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner
├── grunt@0.4.5
├── grunt-contrib-clean@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-jshint@0.6.5
├── grunt-contrib-nodeunit@0.2.2
├── protractor@2.5.0
├── split@0.3.3
└── through2@0.5.1
which is still getting protractor@2.5.
I already did the rm -r node_modules

Comment: For future reference, add your updates to your original question as it will be easier to read. I would recommend removing your node_modules folder as in option 1 of my answer, delete grunt-protractor-runner from your package.json, and then run `npm install && npm install grunt-protractor-runner --save-dev` again

Comment: Ok that is what I thought and then the pop up said if adding comments do it directly and thought that was the rule here. Let me try what you suggested

Comment: If it's minor things, then a comment on my answer is fine. Notice that I made updates to my previous comment as well.

Comment: Posted an comment/answer above